# checked the all checkboxes of form in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

Hi i have form in angularjs and that form have many checkboxes on clicking first checkbox i,e check All i want to checked the all checkboxes . how i can i do that with angular for each field loop here is my sample code I am trying in code snipt.

```js
vm.asas = function() {
  angular.forEach($scope.quizSettingsForm, function(field) {
    console.log(field);
    angular.forEach(field, function(errorField) {
      errorField.$setTouched();
    });
  });
  console.log(vm.QuizSettings);
};
```

```html
<form name="quizSettingsForm" novalidate>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      QUIZ SETTINGS
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" ng-model="vm.checkAll" ng-click="vm.asas()" />
            <label for="checkall">Check /Uncheck ALL</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.QuizSettings.IsOpened" id="Cohort" />
            <label for="Cohort">Have a open Quiz</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.QuizSettings.IsMandatory" id="mandatory" />
            <label for="mandatory">Is Mandatory</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox counterdiv">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.QuizSettings.ShouldExpireAfterExpiry" id="invitation" />
            <label for="invitation">  <p>The quiz will expire <input type="number" ng-model="vm.QuizSettings.Expiry" ng-min="1" name="expiry"> days after invitation</p></label>
            <span class="validation-message" ng-show=" vm.QuizSettings.ShouldExpireAfterExpiry && quizSettingsForm.expiry.$touched && quizSettingsForm.expiry.$error.min"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> The minimum value is 1.</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.QuizSettings.AllowRetakes" id="dontallow" />
            <label for="dontallow">Allow Retake and dont allow more than </label>
            <input type="number" ng-model="vm.QuizSettings.AlllowMoreThen" ng-min="1" name="dontallow"><span style="color: #696969;font-size: 18px;font-weight: normal;"> Retakes </span>
            <span class="validation-message" ng-show="quizSettingsForm.dontallow.$touched && quizSettingsForm.dontallow.$error.min"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> The minimum value is 1.</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

**One Approach** (if checkbox properties are on same object with other properties)

You could (not necessarily should) store property names in an array, and then you could use a `forEach` loop to set the property itself on the `vm.quizSettings` object:

```
function selectAll(){

  var myArray = [
    "IsOpened", 
    "IsMandatory", 
    "ShouldExpireAfterExpiry"
  ];

  angular.forEach(myArray, function(propName){
    vm.QuizSettings[propName] = true;
  });
}
```

**Much Better** (if checkbox properties are alone on same object)

It would be much better if you could avoid storing property names as strings. If all of your checkbox boolean properties to update were alone on it's own object, then it becomes much cleaner:

```
function selectAll(){
  var myArray = Object.keys(vm.QuizSettings);
  angular.forEach(myArray, function(propName){
    vm.QuizSettings[propName] = true;
  });
}
```

**Better Still** (simply decorate the checkboxes that this behavior should apply to)

Create a custom directive `selectAllListener` that listens to a "SelectAll" event and updates `ngModel` value to `true` when that event is raised.

```
function thisDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ngModel){
      scope.$on("SelectAll", function(){
        ngModel.$setViewValue(true);
        ngModel.$render();  
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Add the `select-all-listener` decorator directive to your checkboxes:

```
<li>
  <div class="checkbox" >
    <input select-all-listener type="checkbox" id="checkall" ng-model="vm.checkAll" ng-click="vm.asas()"/>
    <label for="checkall" >Check /Uncheck ALL</label>
  </div> 
</li>
```

Raise the event from within your controller:

```
function selectAll(){
  $rootScope.$broadcast("SelectAll");
}
```

Comment: can i do it with form fields as in my question code

Comment: and what if there is also some obj in vm.QuizSettings beside property

Comment: @Asad That was the assumption with the first answer, to store property names in an array so that you don't overwrite other properties/objects on your `vm.QuizSettings` object.

Comment: well thats cumbersome i think can i do it with angular.foreach field loop ?

Comment: @Asad you can use [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) instead, which works the same way, just a different syntax. I've updated the answer to use `angular.forEach()` instead.

Comment: @Asad You've got several options there now, the custom directive is probably the best approach. I've used events in the example above, but you could also use a service to communicate between controller and directive if you prefer.

Comment: I am looking for field loop but now I maDe the vm model hard code true thanks for your time

Comment: No problem, regarding the "field loop" though, I thought that's what the second option was doing using the [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method, maybe I have misunderstood. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Build an object for your form where isChecked key refers to checkbox value and name refers the label and value refers the model or value of input.

```
$scope.FormAttributeList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "xyz",
        value: "xyz",
        isChecked: false
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "xyz",
        value: "xyz",
        isChecked: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "xyz",
        value: "xyz",
        isChecked: false
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "xyz",
        value: "xyz",
        isChecked: false
    }
]

your code will be like 

<div class="panel-body">
    <ul>
        <li>
           <div class="checkbox" >
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" ng-model="vm.checkAll" ng-click="selectAll(vm.checkAll,FormAttributeList)"/>
                <label for="checkall" >Check /Uncheck ALL</label>
            </div> 
        </li>
        <li ng-repeat="item in FormAttributeList">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.value" id="item.id" />
                <label for="Cohort" >{{item.name}}</label>
            </div>
        </li>
</div>

Now create a function like 

$scope.selectAll = function(checkAll,List) {
    angular.forEach(list,function(value,key){
        value.isChecked = checkAll;
    });
};
```

This is the best way to do what you want it'll remove your unnecessary code.

Comment: This works until you get down to `ShouldExpireAfterExpiry`, where there are other fields e.g. a textbox bound to `vm.QuizSettings.AlllowMoreThen` with it's own validation criteria and message.